# Any progress on Strominger-Yau and Zaslow conjecture?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, vector-bundles, calabi-yau, mirror-symmetry, geometric-langlands

In 2002 [Hausel - Thaddeus](http://geom.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/geom/files/publication/langlands.pdf)  interpreted [SYZ conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYZ_conjecture) in the context of Hitchin system and Langlands duality. Let briefly explain it

Let $\pi : E \to Σ$  a complex vector bundle of rank $r$ and degree $d$ equipped with a hermitian metric on Riemann surface $\Sigma$ . Take th moduli space 
$$M(r, d) = \{(A, Φ) \text{ solving }(\star)\}/\mathcal G $$

(which is a finite-dimensional non-compact space carrying a natural hyper-Kähler  metric)

where

$$F^0_A + [Φ ∧ Φ^∗] = 0 ,\; \;  \bar ∂AΦ = 0\; \; (\star)$$

Here $A$ is a unitary connection on $E$ and $Φ ∈ Ω^{1,0}(End E)$ is a Higgs field. $F^0$ denotes the trace-free part of the curvature and $\mathcal G$ is the unitary gauge group.

$M(r, d)$ is the total space of an integrable system(which can be interpreted by the non-abelian Hodge theory due to Corlette), the [Hitchin fibration](http://web.stanford.edu/~tonyfeng/Yun.pdf), together with [Langlands
duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langlands_dual_group) between Lie groups provides a model for mirror symmetry in the Strominger-Yau and Zaslow conjecture.

As beginner, what is the recent progress on SYZ conjecture and is there any result on Hausel-Thaddeus interpretation in context of framed Riemann surface $(\Sigma, D)$

As more motivation: [Yau-Vafa](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F0-8176-4467-9_11#page-1) introduced semi Ricci flat metric which play important role in the study of Strominger-Yau and Zaslow conjecture

In fact rank 2 Hitchin fibration $$\det: M(2, d) → H^0(Σ, K^2_Σ),\;  [(A, Φ)]→ \det Φ$$. gives rise to semi Ricci flat metric $\omega_{SRF}$ on $ M(2, d)_{reg}$ which still is open to be semi-positive as current. Study of analysis of such semi-Ricci flat metric led to solution of a lot of conjectures in mirror symmetry